# tsql Update with where

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

Currently my worktable looks like this:

```
Portfolio    SEDOL    Grouped    Level
1            111      As Primary 2
1            111      Energy     2
1            122      Financial  2
2            111      Financial  1
2            133      As Primary 1 
2            133      Gas        1
2            123      Oil        1
```

Basically what i want to do is update the worktable where grouped = "As Primary".  You will see that the As Primary record has the same SEDOL as the Primary that it should match to.  It has to match on the level as well as it is possible for a portfolio to only hold the secondary so will have to match on a portfolio with the same level so that there is no error.

I was guessing that the script would have to look something like this:

```
UPDATE @WorkTable
SET Grouped = (SELECT Grouped FROM @Worktable
               WHERE ............... 
WHERE (Select  .............
```

But i'm getting confused as to what to put in my selects.  A point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `UPDATE` with `JOIN`. Something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Grouped = t2.Grouped
FROM @WorkTable t1
INNER JOIN @Worktable t2 ON -- a condition
WHERE -- you can also add conditions here
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @chrissyp - You're welcome any time :) feel free to edit your question if something goes wrong.